# Filter names from textfile

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file where there are names sitting in the first character position.  I am trying to find a way to grep all the names.  Example here I would want the names BUBBA and SUSAN listed.

```
BUBBA =

 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = bubba01)(PORT = xxxx))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = bubba01)
  )
 )

SUSAN =

 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = susan01)(PORT = xxxx))
   )
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SID = susandb)
   )
  )
```

Comment: Please read the description of tags before you add them. `find` is a separate utility used for locating files in a directory rather than lines in a file, and has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want:

`grep -o '^[A-Z]\+'`

`-o` means only output the matching part of the line, and the regex matches a sequence of one or more capital letters at the beginning of a line.

You can also do this sort of thing with `sed`, which is overcomplicated for this example but useful (and simpler than `awk` or `perl`) if you need to do more complex matching or transformation:

`sed -n '/^[A-Z]\+/{s/^\([A-Z]\+\).*/\1/;p}'`

Comment: the flag -o is not recognized

Comment: @Vik which OS are you using?

Comment: @Vik Huh, I didn't realize that `-o` is not specified by posix. So either use the `sed` method, or pipe `grep` without `-o` through `sed`. Though now that I think about it, you could avoid repeating the regex by using conditional branches ... but if you're not using GNU sed, you probably won't have such a useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NF > 1 && $1 !~ /^\(|\)/ {print $1}' file
```

Only print lines with at least one field (`NF > 1`), and ignore lines beginning with `(` or `)`: `^\(|\)`.

Answer (score 0):

If all the input files are formated the same then for a simple awk solution:

`awk '/^[a-Z]/ {print $1}' filename`

Using the carrat (`^`) will select only entries that have a character at the beginning of each line. Then only print the first field ignoring the `=`.